# How can I make this loop with Jinja2?

Tags: python, jinja2

With Jinja2, how can I make an iteration like the folllowing which works with django and not Jinja:

```
{% for key,value in location_map_india.items %}
{{value.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

The above is valid django but with Jinja2 it returns an error message

> TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Jinja2, functions and methods [must be explicitly called](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/switching/#method-calls).

```
{% for key,value in location_map_india.items() %}
{{value.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I wasn't sure I was going to like using Jinja2 over Django, but stuff like this make Jinja2 more pythonic: explicit is better than implicit!