# jinja2 python sort method and added () attempted to explicitly call

Tags: python, sorting, flask, jinja2

I have the following jinja2 code on my webapp html page and I receive the following localhost error when attempting to run the app

> TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'sorted_keys'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endwith'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'with'.

I believe the problem with my code is that I am not calling the python `.sort` method correctly inside jinja2

> `{% sorted_keys.sort() %}`

```
                {% for book in books %}
                  <div class="book">
                  Book: {{book}}
                {% for chapter in books[book]%}
                  <div class="chapter">
                  Chapter: {{chapter}}
                {% with sorted_keys() = books[book][chapter].keys() %}
                {% sorted_keys.sort() %}
                {% for verse in sorted_keys %}
                    <div class="verse">
                    Verse: {{verse}}
                    <div class="verse-text">{{books[book][chapter][verse]}}</div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
                {% endwith %}
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
```

I have researched this post 
[How can I make this loop with Jinja2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975365/how-can-i-make-this-loop-with-jinja2/7975385#7975385)
and edited the sort method as follows

```
                    {% with sorted_keys() = books[book][chapter].keys() %}
                    {% sorted_keys.sort() %}
                    {% for verse in sorted_keys %}`
```

But I receive this error

> TemplateSyntaxError: expected token '=', got '('

I need to sort the list as the output verses do not print in logical order.

https://github.com/phillipsk/webapp/blob/master/templates/bible.html

Comment: you should do the sorting before you hand the list to jinja

Answer (score 0):

First I would just display {[ sorted_keys ]} by itself to make sure you have data in there.  Then to get your sort working use this...

```
{{ sorted_keys | sort }}
```

Also, to get the line above it working use this code.

```
{{ with sorted_keys = books[book][chapter].keys() }}
```

EDIT: ok give these two lines a try...

```
{% set sorted_keys = books[book][chapter].keys() %}
{{ sorted_keys | sort }}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I still received an error TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'sorted_keys' `{{ with sorted_keys = books[book][chapter].keys() }}`
                    `{{ sorted_keys | sort }}` 
                    `{% for verse in sorted_keys %}`https://github.com/phillipsk/webapp/blob/master/templates/bible.html