# How can I obtain zebra styling on dicts with Jinja2?

Tags: jinja2

There is [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21240889/704972) nothing in Jinja2 to get Zebra-styled rows out of the box, and so we do it "by hand".

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    mydict = {'a': 8, 'k': 5, 'e': 7}
    return render_template('index.html', mydict=mydict)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The styling is to alternate between two background colors.

**static/css/mystyle.css**

```
.gray1 { background-color: #bbb; }
.gray2 { background-color: #eee; }
```

I'm using a dict that requires setting up a counter within Jinja. I
hate to be asking a question on five lines of code that set up a
counter, but in cases like these I'm not sure if there is a way to set
up breakpoints, etc to debug the template.

**templates/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
{% block styles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/mystyle.css')}}">
{% endblock %}
<body>
    {% set enum = 0 %}
    {% for item in mydict %}
        {% set enum = (enum + 1) %}
        {% if enum % 2 == 0 %}
            <div class="gray1">
        {% else %}
            <div class="gray2">
        {% endif %}
        {{ item }}: {{ mydict[item] }}<br />
            </div>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
```

How can I obtain zebra styling on dicts with Jinja2? I'm using Bootstrap, and so a solution depending on it would be fine (nice even).

Possibly relevant Q&As: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16306221/8099646) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7975365/8099646)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `loop.index0` or `loop.index` and modulus it to 2 to alternate rows:

```
<style>.alt { background-color: blue }</style>
<ul>
    {% for i in [1,2,3,4,5] %}
        <li class="{% if loop.index0 % 2 %}alt{% endif %}">{{ i }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Alternatively, you can do this in pure CSS:

```
<style>li:nth-child(odd) { background: blue; }</style>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```